# Safely using a flash drive with a fake reported size

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I purchased a 128GB SD card for dirt cheap knowing full well that it was likely too good to be true (unfortunately, I was right...).  My first clue was that copying files to it was quite slow.  My second clue came after finding out that most of the files were corrupt after copying them.  My third clue came after I ejected the drive and reinserted it and Windows said that chkdsk needed to be run on the drive.  I ran H2testw and it seems the drive is actually only 8GB.  Whenever I try to reformat it through Windows it defaults to 128GB which leads me to believe that the drive's firmware was reprogrammed to report the larger size (is that an accurate assumption?).

I'd like to still make use of the drive, perhaps for a Raspberry Pi project or something.  What would be the best way to ensure that I only use the 8GB that actually exists?  My initial thought is to just format the drive to 8GB, but is there anything I should be concerned about with this approach (maybe something like wear leveling attempting to write to a non-existent block)?

Comment: Can you give some hardware specifications of the card?

Comment: I don't have access to the drive at the moment since I'm out of town, but can provide details once I get home.  What sort of details are you looking for?

Comment: I'd contrive a test to see how much you can reliably store on it.  Eg, copy a directory of known size to it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Make an 8G partition on it.

But I did in your place a final test: with a hex a editor I made a marker somewhere around 100G, plugged the drive out, plugged it back and tried to read.

There is another danger: it is possible, that the firmware of the drive remaps a fake 128G to a real 8G flash. Flash drives do this because of they are trying to balance the number of the write operations between their sectors, to make the life of the device longer.

If it is the case, then it matches very well your symptoms, although a such tricky firmware reprogramming probably can't be done by hack. I see a better chance, that a 8G flash had got somehow a 128G firmware.

In this case will work the simple 8G partitioning, too.